# Can we create a HyperDev electron app that connects to the online version?

Tags: electron

I'm interested in making the #hyperDev app available on desktops via the #Electron platform.

I'm wondering if this is possible since the tech behind hyperdev is quite "realtime" and "webservices".

Comment: I believe these are two different things. With hyperdev you can prototype your node/express application quickly. With electron you can build desktop apps with nodejs. Whatever you did in hyperdev, you will have to more or less completely rewrite in electron.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking forwad to do, I just would like to make HyperDev accessible as a desktop app so that I can use it as a replacement for IDEs when working on nodejs/express projects.

Comment: Hyperdev is not an IDE, it's a rapid prototyping platform. You cannot use it as a desktop app. You do not locally edit anything, you do not locally run anything. Hyperdev is also not open source from what I could find (perhaps it is, I just couldn't find it). It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to make it accessible as a Desktop app, then something like http://fluidapp.com might help. Though you might have to work around how Fluid handles opening tabs, or you'll lose the auto-refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nativefier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativefier):

> Nativefier is a command line tool that allows you to easily create a
>   desktop application for any web site with succinct and minimal
>   configuration. Apps are wrapped by Electron in an OS executable (.app,
>   .exe, etc.) for use on Windows, OSX and Linux.

I've successfully applied it to a couple of pages including Hyperdev but haven't checked if all of its functionality remains available.